# How can I decode a Protocol Buffer object with a "message" within another "message"?

Tags: java, ruby, protocol-buffers

I have problems encoding a [Protocol Buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) object in Ruby and decoding it in Java.

On the one hand, I have the following [.proto](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#simple) file:

```
package foo;

message Message {   
    message Stats {
        required string session = 1;
        required string client = 2;
        required string providerCode = 3;
        required string startTime = 4;
        required string endTime = 5;
        required string execTime = 6;
        required string serviceApi = 7;
        required string travelOperation = 8;
        required string serviceOperation = 9;
        required string errorCode = 10;
        required string providerHubStatus = 11;
    }

    required Stats stats = 1;
}
```

When I log the content of the proto object in Ruby (with the function .inspect) the value is:

```
#<Foo::Message stats=#<Foo::Message::Stats session="1888ddb0-4371-55af-92d2-a63436fa5509" client="log" providerCode="EMP" startTime="2016-03-09 15:06:36" endTime="2016-03-09 15:06:40" execTime="3873" serviceApi="hot" travelOperation="avail" serviceOperation="Disponibilidad" errorCode="\\x30" providerHubStatus="OK">>
```

The message seems that is right.

The problem comes when I try to decode the message in Java, the below error happened:

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either than the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
```

---

On the other hand, I've done a test with the following .proto file:

```
package foo;

message Stats {
    required string session = 1;
    required string client = 2;
    required string providerCode = 3;
    required string startTime = 4;
    required string endTime = 5;
    required string execTime = 6;
    required string serviceApi = 7;
    required string travelOperation = 8;
    required string serviceOperation = 9;
    required string errorCode = 10;
    required string providerHubStatus = 11;
}
```

When I log the content of the proto object (message.inspect) the value is:

```
#<Foo::Stats session="1888ddb0-4371-55af-92d2-a63436fa5509" client="log" providerCode="EMP" startTime="2016-03-09 15:06:36" endTime="2016-03-09 15:06:40" execTime="3873" serviceApi="hot" travelOperation="avail" serviceOperation="Disponibilidad" errorCode="\\x30" providerHubStatus="OK">
```

In this case the message seems that is right again, and now, the decoding's going well.

---

Why if I have a unique message "Stats" the decoding is going well and when I have a message within another message the decoding is going wrong?

Should I do something special for the first case?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I can tell you, nothing special on Java side.

I'm having the following dependency in the `pom.xml` of one project where protoc behaves well:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

One hint for debugging: `protoc` has a command line option `--decode` which allows to test binary messages. To pin the problem to one side you should try to deserialize your message with this.

**EDIT**

After validating the outcome of the producing side (ruby) the potential sources for the misbehaving is reduced to:

- network communications
- Java side

  - wrong classes/class version (make sure, you regenerated the deserializer code)
  - bug in `protoc` (*very* unlikely, but possible)

To eleminate one after the other, I'd suppose you try to deserialize the obviously well-formatted package you've already tested with `protoc --decode ...` from disk.

Beware: These are binary data. You must not handle it as string.

Comment: I've put the same dependency as you but I get the same error. I've debugged the binary message that I receive on the Java side. I've used `protoc --decode=foo.Message stats.proto < .\binaryMessage.txt` and the output is `stats {
  session: "c6a34b2f-27b1-4daa-91a5-ac0a84a70b6a"
  client: "log"
  providerCode: "EMP"
  startTime: "2016-03-10 08:24:53"
  endTime: "2016-03-10 08:25:01"
  execTime: "8461"
  serviceApi: "hot"
  travelOperation: "avail"
  serviceOperation: "Disponibilidad"
  errorCode: "\\x30"
  providerHubStatus: "OK"
}`. The message is correct. Where can the error be?

Comment: My project works with the following flux: From Ruby, the message is encoded and it is sent to _GooglePubSub_. After that, a _GoogleDataflow_ streaming job reads the message from _PubSub_ (this message is read as string). During the execution of that job, the function `.getBytes` is used on the message and the output bytes are decoded as _ProtocolBuffer_ object. When I've done the test I've get the message from _PubSub_ and I've done `Files.write(Paths.get("/binaryMessage.txt"), c.element().getBytes());` and this is the file that I've used to execute the **successful** `protoc --decode...`